# xcode 6 app submission failed with itunes store operation issue

Tags: ios, xcode6

[image]

How to fix the issue? Unable to upload new app build using xcode 6 gm seed. In xcode 5 submission passes ok, because IDE explicitly asks username while submission process. Unable to figure out how to set username for xcode 6 for submission process.

The problem is that I have two different AppleIDs for iTunes Connect and Developer Portal, and Xcode 6 probably assumes that I want to use my Developer Portal account for iTunes Connect.

Comment: Probably guys you're using a different AppleID for iTunes Connect than for Developer Portal? @Louie

Comment: I dont know what is the problem with wording of this question @Popeye ? I have the answer, but at most I can put it here, which is not a right place :)

Comment: @Maciek Czarnik yep man, you are right, I have different AppleID. Already thought about giving access to Itunes Connect to my AppleID. But still interested whether I can or not explicitly provide username like it was in previous versions.

Comment: For me the workaround was to export archive in Organizer (Save for iOS App Store Deployment) and then use Application Loader (Xcode > Open Developer Tools > Application Loader) to upload it to iTunes Connect. It allows you to input credentials

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik Thanks, it turns out I have a different error message. So not the same question

Comment: how could anyone possibly think this question is unclear? i'm having  the exact same error.

Comment: The Moderators on this occasion are completely out of order. Nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: Use Application Loader 2.9

Comment: Anyone with a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure why they think it's unclear, but to me it seems like this is not a stackoverflow question since it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application loader to submit the Application. Here is the process given below.

1.) Click on Product > Build For-> profiling. Once your build successful you can find the .app file.
2.) Click on Organizer from Windows option. Click on Derived Data Arrow and you will Navigate your project build folder.
3.) Click on That folder Inside that you will get the Build Folder > Product > Release Zip .app file and then
4.) Click on XCODE > Open Developer Tool > Application loader and then Click on Submit package. After few minute your build will be submitted.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your using different appleID for Itunes store and it is getting conflate,
First export archive from Organizer.
Then Upload Your Binary from latest Application loader(3.0), and use AppleID for iTunes Connect.and still any warning will occurs just ignore and go next.and check your meta Data section(of binary upload) on itunes account add from there and submit for review process.
I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like anyone's actually got to the point here yet - but you just need to add extra Apple developer accounts to Xcode now.

Go to Preferences -> Accounts -> press the '+' button and select 'Add Apple ID'.

Now add in the Apple ID and password for the account from which you want to validate/submit builds, and you will have this new account as an option when you validate/submit.

(Application Loader is a fine workaround for submitting, but sometimes you just want to validate without sending hundreds of MB of data through first, and this is only doable through Xcode)